# preloading images for dynamic css backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I preload large background images before showing them to be used with the css `background-image: url(image);` format. I can use jQuery to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'http://yourhref.com/myimg.jpg'
```

would load the image. With Css:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("myurl.jpg")'
```

Then, when you want to add it,

```
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

Comment: The 'with CSS method', does this cache the image?

Comment: Yes, usually. It depends on the browser, browser version, the expiration of your cache headers, whether or not you're using ssl, etc....but, yes.